# Where can I download Xcode for Mac OS X 10.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xcode

I'm running Mac OS X v 10.4.11 and I want to install Xcode to compile and run ruby on rails.  When I go to apple site I must download latest version of Xcode which does not run on my version of OS X.  Where can I download a version of XCode that i can install in my environment.  Can anyone provide me with a link?

Comment: Have you check if it's on your Tiger disks? That's where I found it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to register on their developer site.

http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_2.5_developer_tools/xcode25_8m2558_developerdvd.dmg

[New Link as of 01/21/2012:]

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/download.action?path=Developer_Tools/xcode_2.5_developer_tools/xcode25_8m2558_developerdvd.dmg

Answer (score 5):

step 1: make a free account here:

connect.apple.com

step 2: go to this link and download:

http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_2.5_developer_tools/xcode25_8m2558_developerdvd.dmg

image size is 900 Megabytes+ 
so enjoy :)

Comment: you have to be signed in to be able to download the file.

Comment: My vote is locked. Edit your message and then comment here again so I see, then I will up vote you.

Answer (score 3):

For those that may want to download Xcode for MacOS X 10.4 (Tiger), you may opt for a "side-channel" solution of downloading the disk image from other sites (e.g., like via torrent sites), since it is quite likely that Apple breaks any of the URLs given above at any point in time *and/or* puts it so buried down their site that it is virtually "unfindable".

In this case, the following data may become handy to ease the pain of future searchers:

- name: `xcode25_8m2558_developerdvd.dmg`
- size: 946768492 bytes
- [SHA1 sum](http://lists.apple.com/archives/security-announce/2007/Oct/msg00001.html): `30884704b0a4b098f02ccbb753958cd5331b8982`
- MD5 sum: `3bd6c24d8fbbdf9007e15861d173764d`

As I am trying to breathe new life to an iBook G3 with Tiger (that works perfectly fine, also with Debian installed), I will use a version of Homebrew called [Tigerbrew](https://github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew), which, of course, depends on Xcode being installed.

Answer (score 2):

XCode is distributed with MacOs, somewhere in additional tools folder or something like that on installer dvd.

Comment: There are also upgrades you can download from the apple site.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 2.5 is the newest version for mac OSX 10.4 (Tiger)

Here's the new link (tested today), the old one is broken:

http://developer.apple.com/mac/scripts/downloader.php?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_2.5_developer_tools/xcode25_8m2558_developerdvd.dmg

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have installation disks, I can upload from mine, but not until tomorow :(. Meanwhile, i recommend You to try NetBeans (whether Ruby, or full version) http://www.netbeans.org/downloads/index.html. I was developing ruby on rails application for my company a year ago, and NetBeans proved to be the best solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

That url works as for 10-2010: http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_2.5_developer_tools/xcode25_8m2558_developerdvd.dmg